# Issue with empty columns in tab delimited text file

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, text-files

i am trying to create a data table from a tab delimited text file.I am getting the values from the file easily.The problem is that when there is a empty column in text file same empty column is not created in data table instead the next non-empty column contents get replaced in the empty columns area

format of data in textfile

```
id    name    product    cost     company name


1      abc    shoe                   xxx
2      xyz    chain                  yyy
```

Data table obtained

```
id    name    product    cost     company name

1      abc     shoe       xxx
2      xyz     chain      yyy
```

my code to getdata

```
var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"d:\d.txt"));
        var table = new DataTable("SampleTable");
        string[] fieldValues = reader.ReadLine().Split(new char[] { '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        for (int i = 0; i < fieldValues.Length; i++)
        {
            table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(fieldValues[i].ToString().Trim()));
        }
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {

            var line = reader.ReadLine().Trim();
            var values = line.Split(new char[] { '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            string[] ee = values;

            var newRow = table.NewRow();
            for (int i = 0; i < ee.Length; i++)
            {
                newRow[i] = ee[i].Trim().ToString(); // like sample [0,0]
            }
            table.Rows.Add(newRow);
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You told `Split` to do exactly what you observe by setting the option `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` - it removes empty entries.

Remove this option and it will keep the empty column.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an empty column, then you should read an empty string, not a null string.

In other words....

**1,abc,shoe,,xxx**

The reason your getting the result your getting is because of this: **StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries**

Answer (score 3):

The problem might be that you split the line with the `RemoveEmptyEntries` option:

```
var values = line.Split(new char[] { '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

The empty cell gets removed. Omit this parameter and it should work...